# django-tables2: Changing default column title of a foreign key column

Tags: django, django-tables2

How do I change the column title for a foreign value in django-tables2?

**Model**

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=16)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name', max_length=16)
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer, verbose_name='Employer')
```

**Table**

```
class EmployeeTable(tables.Table)
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeTable
        fields = ('name', 'employer.name')
```

**Output**

```
Name | Name
Bill | Steve
```

I would like to override the default column headers to provide more meaningful information.

**Preferred output**

```
Employee name | Employer name
Bill          | Steve
```

**Table (not working)**

```
class EmployeeTable(tables.Table)
    name = tables.Column(verbose_name='Employee name')          # <-- Works!
    employer.name = tables.Column(verbose_name='Employer name') # <-- Doesn't work!
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeTable
        fields = ('name', 'employer.name')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. You have to use an `Accessor`.

```
from django_tables2.utils import Accessor

class EmployeeTable(tables.Table)
    name = tables.Column(verbose_name='Employee name')
    employer_name = tables.Column(verbose_name='Employer name', orderable=False, accessor=Accessor('employer.name'))
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeTable
        fields = ('name', 'employer_name')
```